# How do I convert text files to .arff format(weka)

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, hierarchical-clustering

Please advise me How do I convert text files to .arff format(weka)
because i wan to do data clustering for 1000 txt file.

regards

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915683/how-to-convert-a-log-system-file-into-arff-format
Be advised that Weka is only good on classification, its clustering capabilities are pretty much nonexistant.

Answer (score 1):

There are some converters implemented in WEKA, just find the right format or make little changes to your data (using awk, sed...).

Here is the API pages related to this topic: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/converters/package-summary.html

For exapmle here is how to convert from CSV to ARFF:

```
java weka.core.converters.CSVLoader filename.csv > filename.arff
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use

```
package text.Classification;
import java.io.*;
import weka.core.*;
public class TextDirectoryToArff {

public Instances createDataset(String directoryPath) throws Exception {
FastVector atts;
FastVector attVals;
atts = new FastVector();
atts.addElement(new Attribute("contents", (FastVector) null));
String[] s = { "class1", "class2", "class3" };
attVals = new FastVector();
for (String p : s)
    attVals.addElement(p);
atts.addElement(new Attribute("class", attVals));
Instances data = new Instances("MyRelation", atts, 0);
System.out.println(data);

InputStreamReader is = null;
File dir = new File(directoryPath);
String[] files = dir.list();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].endsWith(".txt")) {
    double[] newInst = new double[2];
    File txt = new File(directoryPath + File.separator + files[i]);

    is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(txt));
    StringBuffer txtStr = new StringBuffer();

    int c;
    while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        txtStr.append((char) c);
    }
    newInst[0] = data.attribute(0).addStringValue(txtStr.toString());
    int j=i%(s.length-1);
    newInst[1] = attVals.indexOf(s[j]);
    data.add(new Instance(1.0, newInst));

    }
}
return data;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

TextDirectoryToArff tdta = new TextDirectoryToArff();
try {
    Instances dataset = tdta.createDataset("/home/asadul/Desktop/Downloads/text_example/class5");
    PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter("/home/asadul/Desktop/Downloads/text_example/abc.arff", "UTF-8");
    fileWriter.println(dataset);
    fileWriter.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

}